# What is the maximum number of vertices given a number of edges?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science

What is the largest number of vertices in a graph with 35 edges if all vertices are of degree at least 3?

I thought up of a solution but there are some questions I could not find.

***Solution*** 
Maximum degree of a graph >= Sum of degree of individual vertices
2E >= deg(V1) + deg(V2) + ... + deg(Vn)
2 * 35 >= 3 + 3 + ... + 3            ...(I), 
70 >= 3n
23.33 >= n or 23 >= n

So the largest number of vertices are 23, with the given constraints.

***Question***

If we are considering the degree of each of the vertices to be 3, then shouldn't the number of vertices be even i.e 22 ?(since number of odd degree vertices in a graph are even)

Comment: Someone argued that the largest number of vertices are 23, having 22 vertices of degree 3 and one vertice of degree 4. Then the inequality at (I) is void since we are assuming every vertice to be of degree 3 and then solving the inequality further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't know that all vertices have degree $3$, only that their degree is *at least* $3$. Therefore your argument that there cannot be an odd number of vertices doesn't work.

Your argument that $70 \ge 3n$ still works in essentially the same way; the initial inequality should just be written as
$$ 2E = \text{sum of degrees} \ge 3+3+\cdots+3 = 3n $$

---

You still need to prove that $23$ is indeed possible, for example, by showing a concrete graph with $23$ vertices (of degree $\ge 3$) and $35$ edges.

One way to make such a graph would be:

- Start with your favorite 3-regular graph on $22$ vertices (for example, the edge graph of an 11-sided prism). It has $33$ edges, so we need to add one vertex and two edges.
- Take one of the edges, and bisect it by a new vertex. That gets us up to $34$ edges. The new vertex so far has degree only $2$, but fortunately we still need to add one edge.
- Add an edge from your new vertex to one of the existing vertices (which it isn't already connected to). This gives the new vertex degree $3$ and the other endpoint degree $4$, which is allowed.